# Determining presence of firewall using python on linux

Tags: python, linux

I want to display whether firewall is present or not.. if it is not enabled, the user should get an alert.. can it be done using python code?

Comment: What do you mean by the presence of firewall in Linux? Linux has `netfilter` and `iptables` built in the kernel since 2.4.

Comment: i want to write a program in python which will display whether firewall is activated or not.. can it b done in normal user mode?? i mean without being root??

Answer (score 2):

This is the command I executed in Redhat machine with firewall off

```
[root@epmauto-165-253 ~]# service iptables status
iptables: Firewall is not running.
[root@epmauto-165-253 ~]#
[root@epmauto-165-253 ~]# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, May  1 2012, 13:52:17)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> status = os.popen("service iptables status").read()
>>> print status
iptables: Firewall is not running.

>>>
```

And the following command executed when firewall was on, at different redhat machine.

```
[root@blr-srm-auto157 ~]# service iptables status
Table: filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
5    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

[root@blr-srm-auto157 ~]# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Apr 11 2011, 15:50:32)
[GCC 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> status = os.popen('service iptables status').read()
>>> print status
Table: filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
5    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination


>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In GNU/linux the firewall (netfilter) is part of the kernel, so I think that if linux is on, the firewall is too.
next, you may ask netfilter if it is configured, and if is there any rules. for this you might parse iptables command (such as iptables -L) output.